# Jquery sending the data using post

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to send some  data to the server.

on the server it should be going to www.sample.com/data2

I have a Array as arrays;
var = arrays;
this arrays has the value.

I am doing

```
$.post('/data2', {arrays});
```

This is not working...
this is inside the .submit(). I can see in firebug it is giving Error for the variable as "invalid object initializer"

Comment: Show us the **EXACT ERROR MESSAGE**. Your own interpretation from memory is never helpful

Comment: the data2 is not seeing this values I am sending. Firebox shows the error as : syntaxError: invalid object initialize at the post line

Comment: Firefox tells no lie: `{arrays}` is not a valid object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming your var `arrays` is

`[1,2,3,etc..]`

which you can't just wrap with `{}` brackets...you need to give a key to your value, such as..

`{"arr" : arrays}`

If your using PHP, your array would be held in the $_POST array in the index "arr", like...

`$arr = $_POST['arr'];`

Comment: Thank you this resolved the error but I dont see  that data is going to sever. I am using javascript. I saw this Error: NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument..not sure what is the issue/Errot I have in the post line

Comment: I dont know that error, what language server side language is it?

Comment: I dont see it is server side error the client is not sending the server

Answer (score 1):

Objects in javascript are essentially key-value mappings, which means that attempting to define an object literal with an unlabelled value (inside the `{}` block) will throw a syntax error.

You should instead provide a key for the data, e.g. `{"data" : arrays}`.

As usual the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide%2FValues%2C_Variables%2C_and_Literals#Object_literals) [pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) on this facet of javascript is thorough and informative if you would like some further reading.